# IntelliJ/WebStorm node.js code completion with (custom) required modules not working / unresolved function?

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, webstorm

If I have, for example, this code (`posts.js`)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var postsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: Number,
    title: String,
    description: String,
    comments: [{ type: String, minlength: 1, required: true }]
});    
var Post = mongoose.model('Posts', postsSchema);    
module.exports = Post;
```

and will use this model somewhere e.g.:

```
var Post = require('../models/posts');
Post.{strg+space}
```

it will work but I can't use code completion and I will see an error with "unresolved function" in IntelliJ editor if I call a function.

If I change the export to:

```
module.exports = {Post:Post};
```

or

```
exports.Post = Post;
```

and import the model:

```
var Post = require('../models/posts').Post;
```

everything seems to be fine.

Is this a bug or did I do something wrong?

[image: code completition problem]

[image: code completition after export with identifier]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known issue, please follow [WEB-17099](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17099) for updates

Answer (score 0):

The IDE does not maintain the symbols from user written js files by default. You need to add them explicitly to a project for them to be available in the code completion.

You can add a file or a library by going to Settings -> Language & Frameworks -> Javascript -> Libraries.

Then click on Add and add your file using the + button.
It gives you an options to even add an entire directory.

Comment: i tried this already but it will not change anything in the described behaviour. as i said it will work if export my model with an identifier.

Comment: Did you enable the Node.js Core library under Settings -> Language & Frameworks -> Node.js and NPM ??

Comment: yes. i made some screenshots to make it clearer. the code completition and the resolve error is gone if i export it with an identifier but it is not really ok because it show to much.